# Difficulties in installation of pysparse and superlu

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, python-module, finite-element-analysis

I want to run a python2.7 program ([this one](https://github.com/williamhunter/topy)). I'm having a lot of trouble (I spend my whole aftenoon on this), because of the installation of the python 2.7 dependencies.

**Config**

I am running an Ubuntu 16.04 64bits ([Mint XFCE 18), based on Debian. My computer is a Dell Inspiron N5110 from 2011, with dual boot W7/U16. The keyboard-to-screen interface is really new in this world and perhaps need to learn a lot more about it to solve this alone.

**Proceeds**

I started by installing various programs with apt:

`sudo apt-get install -y git python-dev libpython-dev libevent-dev libsuperlu-dev libblas-dev liblapack-dev`

After *git cloning* the program I wanted, I installed the dependencies. I don't know why, but `sudo pip install pysparse` didn't worked. Instead, `sudo pip install csc-pysparse` worked fine.

**Issue**

When I run my program, it tells me `from pysparse import superlu, itsolvers, precon` and then `ImportError: cannot import name superlu`.

Why ? Isn't the pip resolving the dependencies problems it could have and install superlu ? Do I need to install superlu manually or to install the pysparse instead of csc-pysparse ?

(and please be indulgent, It's my really first post on stackoverflow, as [thoses](https://github.com/williamhunter/topy/issues/9) were my really firsts posts on github)

Comment: (If anyone want to know more details, it's a free [topology optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topology_optimization) program. It finds out the best topology for stressed geometries, I'm kind of passionate about this but I don't have the coding skills yet)

Answer (score 0):

I did get an [answer](https://github.com/williamhunter/topy/issues/9), thanks to [William Hunter](https://github.com/williamhunter).

The procedure to install it is the following :

```
sudo apt-get install -y python-dev python-tk libpython-dev libevent-dev libsuperlu-dev libblas-dev liblapack-dev libatlas3-base libatlas-dev
sudo pip install matplotlib setuptools SymPy pysparse pyvtk
```